# How can I change the angle of an edge loop?

Tags: modeling, edges

How can I change the angle of an object like at 19:44 of https://youtu.be/mu9J0D6ebVw?t=1167 when he adds wingtips?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you mean Shear? <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> with selected vertices, then drag the mouse cursor around to effect the amount.

[image]

But I think he uses a simple Rotate (<kbd>R</kbd>), with the pivot point set to *Median Point*, then move the mouse to adjust the rotation amount.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I saw the tutorial and there is nothing fancy about it. You have to just rotate the edge. Here is what you need to do:

1. Select the edge loop. Set the *pivot type* to a ***3D Cursor***.
   [image]
2. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>-->*Snap*-->***Cursor to Selected*** and set the cursor as pictured below.
   [image]
3. In this case the edge is not regular. You may fix it by pressing <kbd>S</kbd>, then <kbd>X</kbd> (or <kbd>Y</kbd> or <kbd>Z</kbd>, depending on your situation) and then <kbd>0</kbd>.
   [image]
4. Now you have the even edge. ***Rotate it using*** <kbd>**R**</kbd> and moving the mouse from right to left (or input the degree value).
   [image]
5. Extrude the edge (<kbd>E</kbd>). And this is it!
   [image]