# Is there way to move one vertex and make another move with it proportionally?

Tags: edit-mode

I'll try to explain in this gif. I am doing this manually in 2 steps - rotate, scale. And I select all vertexes. Is there instrument rotate them in one step or can I move one and make other move too?

[image: gif]

Comment: Do you want to make edges angled while retaining the straight initial horizontal loops? Maybe related -https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30970/how-can-i-change-the-angle-of-an-edge-loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by @MrZak you can use Shear (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>)

[image]

Form the [Blender Manual:](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/transform/shear.html?highlight=shear)

> Shearing is a form of movement where parallel surfaces move past one another. During this transform, movement of the selected elements will occur along the horizontal axis of the current view. The axis location will be defined by the Pivot Point. Everything that is “above” this axis will move (Shear) in the same direction as your mouse pointer (but always parallel to the horizontal axis). Everything that is “below” the horizontal axis will move in the opposite direction.

Comment: Good to know about this one hidden tool, thanks! Thats the correct answer I am sure :)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure there is a one-step method for this. But if your model is aligned like in your example, you can try this (while holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> when scaling to enable snapping - it also needs to be set to vertex).

[image]

But especially for your example, you can just cut the mesh with Knife tool (<kbd>K</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for showing snapping! Did not know about this

Comment: That shear function is what you want, I also didn't know that! :) For the snapping - I can't live with it! You can simply select what you want to snap to by Ctrl+Shift+Tab and then whenever you grab, you can press Ctrl to enable the snapping. Such a powerful function, especially if you model using the viewport grid - it is very easy and quick too achieve perfect precision then.