# Loop cut at an angle

Tags: modeling

I need to add an edge to a model at an angle without distorting the overall shape.

[image]

I can add a loop cut and rotate, but this skews the model

[image]

I'd like to keep the lines consistent, so I don't want to deal with scaling after rotating. I'd assume there is an easier way to do that, but maybe not.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of doing a loop cut you can use the *Knife* tool.

1. Press <kbd>K</kbd> to start the knife tool.
2. Optional step: If you need to cut 'through' the mesh (so the cut goes all the way around) press <kbd>Z</kbd> to toggle the *Cut through* option on.
3. Click once above the mesh and once below to create a cut across the mesh:

[image]

4. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to confirm the cut.

Comment: An alternative is to use the Shear tool on a loop cut: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/91109/is-there-way-to-move-one-vertex-and-make-another-move-with-it-proportionally/91115#91115